# Last version of Chrome for Nexus 7 2013 2nd gen.?

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, chrome-for-android, nexus-7

I've just got hold of an old Nexus 7 2013 2nd gen., running 6.0.1 Marshmallow. After resetting, the Play Store downloads updates, and I can install the latest version of Firefox and the last version of Opera for Marshmallow (72). Chrome only updates to 95. Everything I've read suggests I can run 106, and I can certainly sideload later versions.

Why would Chrome stop at 95? Is there any way get it to update without resorting to sideloading? If you've got the same tablet running the stock OS, what version of Chrome did you stop on?

Comment: I have a similar issue with a Lenovo Yoga Tab 3 Pro. Chrome permanently displays an 'Update Available' icon to the right of the address bar, but the Play Store does not show any updates available.

Comment: Based on [the captured variants on APK Mirror](https://www.apkmirror.com/apk/google-inc/chrome/#variants), looks like v106 should be supported for Android 6.0+. However, for Play Store itself, I'm afraid it's hard to answer without knowing which versions Google are still putting up online because they could pull out some older APKs without mentioning any reason.

Comment: Make sure you have installed the latest version of Google PlayServices. They usually update automatically after some hours or days but some times you have to trigger it manually. An old PlayServices version could prevent download of newer Chrome versions.

Comment: @Fat Monk - Exactly this! Good to know I'm not alone.

Comment: @Robert - 23.03, which I think is current. That was my first suspect, as I've had to sideload Play Services on (even) older devices to get them updating again.

Comment: @robert same as jetboy here .. GPS 23.03 which was released a couple of weeks ago. Going direct to the GPS page on the play store does not offer any updates (just the option to deactivate). Have also tried clearing GPS and Play Store caches and data... No change. Still no Chrome update - currently on 95.0.4638.74 releases in 2nd November 2021.

Comment: @Fat Monk Your Yoga Pad is on Marshmallow too right? Is this a device you've had since it was current, or something you've got hold of more recently? Reason for the question: The Nexus 7 is for a device lab for website testing, and I'm trying to get it into as patched a state as a regular owner would have it. If that means Chrome stops at 95, that'd be fine. If other Marshmallow tablets are the same, it'd lead me to think this is the norm.

Comment: @jetboy yes, Marshmallow. And yes, I've had it since new and kept it as up to date as possible - sadly Lenovo dropped updates very quickly and slowly software is starting to fail now as support for older Android API versions is dropped. Frustrating as there are no comparable tablets on the market these days (form factor, projector etc).

Comment: @Fat Monk Maybe a candidate for Lineage? A long shot, but do you have Firefox or Edge installed from the Play Store? If so, which versions?